# Simple query with different execution plan when executed from SQL Job agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have this quite simple query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM system.RawEvent_pool1 WHERE ProcessedDate IS NULL)
EXECUTE [system].[usp_ProcessAuditData] '1'
```

I have a filtered index on system.RawEvent_pool1.

It is filtered on ProcessedDate IS NULL 
(ProcessedDate is included in the index)

So the index should be a perfect match for this query.

From the actual execution plan, I can tell, that when executed from Management Studio the index is used as expected.

But when executing the exact same query on the same database from a SQL Job Agent, the index is not used.

Instead, the query plan uses the clustered index on the primary key for the table.

This I can see in the Query Store.

Additional info: The job is executed under a different account.

Is there any logical explanation for this behavior?

Then I would love to hear it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.

The SQL Job Agent has 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' set to 'OFF' by default.

Executing 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' will make the statement use the expected execution plan

But I still have no clue why this works.

Comment: found the reason, and what about solution?

Comment: As stated... ''SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' will make the statement use the expected execution plan'